# How to get the call-to-action type using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-call-to-action

I want to check whether a facebook post contains call-to-action button, if yes, then what the type is:

'open_link, like_page, shop_now, play_game, install_app, use_app, install_mobile_app, use_mobile_app, book_travel, listen_music, learn_more, sign_up, download, watch_more, no_button, call_now, apply_now, buy_now, get_offer, get_offer_view, get_directions, message_page, message_user, subscribe, sell_now, donate_now, get_quote, contact_us, start_order, record_now, vote_now, register_now, request_time, see_menu, email_now, open_movies'

I tried to search it using facebook explorer but I cannot find anythings:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

How to do that using facebook api if I have the post id and an access token?

Comment: What kind of access token? Would not surprise me if that info was only available if you have admin access to the page ...

Comment: I just got a user/app access token. The call-to-action type can be viewed by open the facebook page.It means it is opened to public. I can check by using browser but I want to do that using facebook api. How to do it?

Comment: UI and API are two very different things, publicly visible via UI does not automatically mean publicly available via API, too. Try this using a page access token for the page the posts are on, and see if you get a different result.